# Order by count from multiple columns of same table

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I've following columns: team_id, player_id, league_id, coach_id, venue_id in a posts table.Any given post can have bunch of id on each column.

[image: This is my table example.]

Now, I want to order by DESC count of any id.
For example:The result should be: 
3 - league_id //because it has count total of 3 
7 - team_id  // because it as count total of 2 
8 - player_id //because it has count of 2 and so on. 
Basically, We order by count DESC but it has to be fro same column count. 
Any way i can get it? It also has to give me column name so that i know the id from that column.
Thank you!

Comment: What is the data type of your columns?  Why are you trying to store multiple values in a single column?  That is not the best data model for relational databases.  Are you sure you are using MySQL?  Some databases support an array type, but MySQL is not one of them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Data type is text.  I'm storing multiple values for basically tagged item in post.  Yeah its MySQL.

Comment: . . I would advise you to fix the data model using multiple association/junction tables rather than trying to figure out how to do this.  It is just not worth the effort to deal with a bad data model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper data model would have a separate junction/association table for each relationship:

- `post_teams`
- `post_players`
- `post_leagues`
- `post_coaches`
- `post_venues`

Each of these would have properly declared foreign key relationships to the two referenced tables.

With such a model, your query would actually be pretty simple:

```
select which, id, count(*)
from ((select post_id, team_id as id, 'team' as which
       from post_teams
      ) union all
      (select post_id, players_id as id, 'players' as which
       from post_players
      ) union all
      (select post_id, leagues_id as id, 'leagues' as which
       from post_leagues
      ) union all
      (select post_id, coach_id as id, 'coach' as which
       from post_coaches
      ) union all
      (select post_id, venue_id as id, 'venue' as which
       from post_venues
      )
     ) x
group by which, id
order by count(*) desc;
```

I would advise you to fix your data model -- or switch to a database that has native support for arrays.  MySQL has a great method for storing lists.  It is called a *table*, not a string.